# Symfony - render $_GET variable in a form field

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a register form, in one field I want to store a $_GET variable from the URL, but everytime I refresh the page, the form field is blank.
Where's the problem?

```
$license = $request->query->get('lic');
$form->get('extra')->setData($license);
```

where 'lic' is the value passed in the URL and 'extra' is the form field in which i want to store the value.

Comment: You make sure that `$request->query->get('lic')` returns a not `null` value ?

Comment: does the extra field exist in your form type? Assuming that it is a valid value, pass it into your form when building to set the value

Comment: @Rooneyl Yes, the extra field exists in my form type. Do you mean to pass it into the buildForm() function?

Comment: yes, pass it in as a custom option, that set of that